# How can I install third party libraries into the spcified Python version if I have multiple Python versions?

Tags: python, numpy, installation

I'm using ubuntu 10.04. The default version of Python is 2.6.5, but I need Python 2.7.

So I install Python 2.7 using "make altinstall "according to this webpage https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-10-04 .

```
./configure
make
sudo make altinstall
```

But when I use the newly installed python:

```
$ python2.7 setup.py
```

the numpy library which I installed before doesn't work any more. It raised ImportError:

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

It seems I have to install it again. I made use of "apt-get" to install numpy before. Now I'm wondering if I should download the source code of numpy and specify the location where it should be installed. But I don't know how to specify the path. So, any suggestions?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but Ubuntu 12.10 is out. 10.04 isn't really supported any more.

Comment: I would suggest using easy_install to install numpy instead of the ubuntu package. On ubuntu easy_install should be available different versions corresponding to the different python interpreters installed (version number appears as a suffix).

Answer (score 1):

How about using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

This provides you a virtual environment with specified version of python.